# Formal verification on Hardhat

Tags: hardhat, formal-verification

Is there any tool to be able to do formal verification on hardhat projects that's open source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some great open source FV tools are the [SMT Checker](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/smtchecker.html) by the solidity team  (there's a [nice introduction thread here](https://twitter.com/0xOwenThurm/status/1614359896350425088)) and [manticore](https://github.com/trailofbits/manticore) maintained by Trail of Bits.

For a detailed overview of Formal Verification, you can check out [this repo](https://github.com/leonardoalt/ethereum_formal_verification_overview).

Answer (score 0):

Certora also has a variety of tools to help you with contract security including formal verification: https://demo.certora.com/

Comment: Yeah, sadly I need an open source tool for this specific project